# qt slots and signalls autoconnecting

Tags: qt, qt5, signals-slots, qt5.2

I am using Qt 5.2.1. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383845/qmetaobjectconnectslotsbyname-no-matching-signal-for-error-when-building-on), and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355023/qmetaobjectconnectslotsbyname-no-matching-signal) - it doesn't cover my case. I have QSqlTableModel , and a window that uses it. I want to react on its [dataChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) signal:

```
void QAbstractItemModel::​dataChanged(const QModelIndex & topLeft, const QModelIndex & bottomRight, const QVector<int> & roles = QVector<int> ())
```

So I initialize the model in my windowClass constructor like this:

```
kontrahentModel = new QSqlTableModel(this);
```

And heres the slot declaration:

```
void on_kontrahentModel_dataChanged(const QModelIndex & topLeft, const QModelIndex & bottomRight, const QVector<int> & roles = QVector<int> ());
```

Same number of arguments - but it results in the infamous

> QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for (...)

What did I miss? Does it only work for GUI signals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by accident while writing this question... My model was missing a name. When I added

```
kontrahentModel->setObjectName("kontrahentModel");
```

All worked like a charm...

BUT - "there is no rose without a thorn". When assigning a parent for the model, an old problem returns - described here: [QSqlQueryModel with a parent - app crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660089/qsqlquerymodel-with-a-parent-app-crash)